# SNOWFLAKE querying column name with Spaces

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to use agg functions to query data, I have space in the column name in SNOWFLAKE

```
select item, avg(item price) from order group by item;
```

The error is

```
Numerical value '1212.11' is not recognized
```

Expected output is

Code which gives item and avg price of that item

Comment: Why not alter the table to fix the column name instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try

select item, try_to_number(avg("item price")) from order group by item;

Answer (score 0):

If you try add " (double quotes) around the column name does that help?

```
select item, avg("item price"::INT) from order group by item;
```

The ::INT just casts it to a datatype that can be summed. You should take a peak at the [datatypes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types.html) available to find one that best suits your needs. (2 dp might be good for currency)

Another possibility is :

```
select item, avg( price ) from order group by item;
```

That's if you don't have a column called "item price" rather 2 columns "item" and "price".